# Is nested table available in Sphinx? If so how can I use it?

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext

```
.. list-table:: Title
   :widths: 25 20 30 30
   :header-rows: 1

   * - Field Name
     - Data Type
     - Values
     - Description
   * - boiling_point_f
     - JSON
     - testing
     - .. list-table:: testTitle
          :widths: 25 25 50
          * - test1
          * - test2
          * - test3
```

[image: The output can be seen here]

I've tried linking csv file too, but cannot get the desired output.

Comment: No, but you can use the [`raw` directive](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/rst/directives.html#raw-data-pass-through) and HTML.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please prefer code as image when you ask quesiton : https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question

Answer (score 0):

The nested table would also fail stand-alone. Insert a blank line after the options block and match the number of "width" arguments to the number of table columns.

```
.. list-table:: Title
   :widths: 25 20 30 30
   :header-rows: 1

   * - Field Name
     - Data Type
     - Values
     - Description
   * - boiling_point_f
     - JSON
     - testing
     - .. list-table:: testTitle
          :widths: 25
          
          * - test1
          * - test2
          * - test3
```